# QGIS form with live shapes based on attributes

Tags: qgis, html

I have a form with some sliders that set attributes (used to create a shape, a tree canopy). I would like to be able to show a preview of the shape. A rough section of code is shown below which draws a curve but only when reviewing the features - can it be persuaded to do it live?

[image]

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
<script> 
var C_N = expression.evaluate("\"N\"");
var C_E = expression.evaluate("\"E\"");
var C_S = expression.evaluate("\"S\"");
var C_W = expression.evaluate("\"W\"");
const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(C_W, 0);
ctx.bezierCurveTo( C_W,0, (C_W+C_E),C_N, C_W,(C_S + C_N));
ctx.stroke();
</script>
```